# Изменить схему Proteus - сигнализация (схема прилагается)

Tags: avr, proteus

Схема пропала. Вопрос исчерпан.

Answer (score 1):

Вы точно нарисовали схему. Микросхема ATMEGA16 выпускается в двух корпусах. Цоколевка выводов разная. И они оба не совпадают со схемой. Сверте с описанием микросхемы : http://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/78532/ATMEL/ATMEGA16/259/2/ATMEGA16.html.
И вот такая есть в интернете: http://cxem.net/mc/mc59-3.png . В программной части должно быть тестирование индикатора (перебором) и проверки замкнутости датчиков. После этого схема переходит в следящий режим. Удачи.

Comment: как можно изменить данную схему? Ту, которую вы скинули, я бы не смог сделать. Мне необходимо по минимуму простая сигнализация с светодиодом и ревуном. Имеющийся код совсем иной. Разу уж это конкурсный вопрос, помогите. Тем более я не скрываю, ничего не понимаю.

Comment: Ваша схема для микросхемы в корпусе PDIP с двухрядным расположением выводов:  =[]=
Для проверки

Comment: померяйте питание:
цифровое [10], аналоговое [30],
сброс [9] == лог "1" ,
 проверте тактовую частоту [12] == " /\/\ ", 
проверте логическое состояние шин. PC0-PC6 лог. ноль "0" (индикатор не горит) PC7 "0" зуммер молчит и светодиод не горит.  
Проверте другие шины PA0-PA7, PB0-PB7 и PD0-PD7 на "нет контакт или лишний контакт". И если это не помогло, опишите как схема не работает, что с ней не так.

Comment: Подправил вопрос